# Growing a visual tree with rectangles?

Tags: lua, geometry

Given rectangle-shaped bars (say, of size 50x10), how would I grow-draw them to something that looks like a tree? A starting point is given where a semi-randomly bar is added, and then a new bar or two are added to every end of the old rotation, rotated by themselves, and with new bars added at their end, and so on to some point. I suppose it's a geometry question -- how do I find the correct bar ends to stick the new rotated bar too?

I'm using Lua, but any pseudocode would help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like a tree.  You'd better use fractal-generated trees like [this one](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_2Ow0Joj3t6w/Sam3IJ1M5JI/AAAAAAAAADA/hO13-f_rm_A/S1600-R/fractal-tree2.jpg).

Comment: Thanks, but it is supposed to look like the tree-ish thing (whatever it may be called) I drew as sample, including potential for these overlaps. So it may indeed not be a "real" tree, but it's what I need (this is randomized game content where the branches have specific puzzle purpose).

Comment: Have you looked into matrix transformations? Also, to clarify: do you mean your input is a certain number and size of bars, and your task is to just to stick them together into a random branch structure?

Comment: To clarify, it's for a game I'm making and I define a fixed size of branch (always the same width and height), and I know how to handle the loop where they'll be stuck together and rotated and such -- except I don't know how, given the last branches x, y, and rotation, to find the right x, y for the new branch for a given semi-random rotation so that it will be stuck seamlessly to the end of the last one. Perhaps matrix transformations are the way to go but I don't specifically know about applying them here.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [L-systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system). They can be used to create plant-like structures. The Wikipedia article has many references to sites where you can toy with these.

Comment: Thanks, but my goal is to have a fixed-size branches kind of "tree-ish" thing like drawn above, not a real or fractal tree...

Comment: The different widths of common L-system renderings are only for aesthetic reasons; you can draw them with uniform thickness. As for lengths, these are usually described using repetitions. So if your replacement rules don't duplicate symbols without turns in between, you won't get longer lines. On the other hand, your question doesn't preclude joining multiple boxes in the same direction, and it definitely gives a treeish look to things.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand well the core of your problem: you have a segment (bar) which you rotate around one of its sides by some angle and you want to know the position of the other end of the bar after that.

Isn't what you're looking for just the geometric definition of sine and cosine?

See below, sorry for my awful drawing skills :)

[image]

To make it "stick" just rotate around the right corner of the rectangle depending on the angle, like so:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the image, I should have done an image like that from the start. So here is my try now to explain better: http://i.imgur.com/lUAQzdm.png What would be the pseudo code for that?

Comment: What is "rotation"? Meaning: what is the position of a bar with 0 rotation? What is the unit (radian, degrees)? And what is the axis (center of the bar)?

Comment: It's rotation in degrees around the center of the bar; 0 degrees could be defined as anything but at the moment is a horizontal bar. In the meantime, I've switched to manually creating shapes -- the tree now being just one of many in the game -- though I'm still interested if there's an answer.

Comment: Hmm, there is an answer but it's long to explain in details and I don't have time for that now. You must first compute the positions of the corners of the 1st bar (pure geometry) then make one of the corners of the 2nd bar correspond to one of the 1st bar. The tricky part is to choose the right corners. The idea is that the intersection of the bars must be non-empty...